# Python .split() function

Tags: python, arcpy

I am using split to separate the M/D/Y values from one field to make them in their own respective fields. My script in bombing out on the NULL values in the original date field for the Day field.

10/27/1990   ---->  M:10   D:27  Y:1990

```
# Process: Calculate Field Month
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="Assess_Template",field="Assess_Template.Month",expression="""!Middleboro_xlsx_Sheet2.Legal_Reference_Sale_Date!.split("/")[0]""",expression_type="PYTHON_9.3",code_block="#")

# Process: Calculate Field Day
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="Assess_Template",field="Assess_Template.Day",expression="""!Middleboro_xlsx_Sheet2.Legal_Reference_Sale_Date!.split("/")[1]""",expression_type="PYTHON_9.3",code_block="#")

# Process: Calculate Field Year
arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table="Assess_Template",field="Assess_Template.Year",expression="""!Middleboro_xlsx_Sheet2.Legal_Reference_Sale_Date!.split("/")[-1]""",expression_type="PYTHON_9.3",code_block="#")
```

I am unsure how I should fix this issue; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you will need to either guard the `split()`, e.g. `x.split('/') if x else x` or fix the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (to calculate the year where possible):

```
in_table = "Assess_Template"
field = "Assess_Template.Year"
expression = "get_year(!Middleboro_xlsx_Sheet2.Legal_Reference_Sale_Date!)"
codeblock = """def get_year(date):
    try:
        return date.split("/")[-1]
    except:
        return date"""

arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table, field, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

Good luck!

Tom